# Remove duplicates from a CardArray

Tags: java

im currently having Issues with removing duplicates of a Card in a given CardArray. My current Code is attached. My Issue isnt removing duplicates themself, but how to put the Cards from the Set back into the CardArray, as that is required from the Task.

```
public Card[] removeDuplicates(Card[] arrayToHandle) {
        
        int end = arrayToHandle.length;
        int counter = 0;
        Set<Card> cardSet = new HashSet<Card>();

        for(int i = 0; i < end; i++){
          cardSet.add(arrayToHandle[i]);
        }

        
        Iterator<Card> it = cardSet.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            arrayToHandle[counter] = it.next();
            counter++;
        }
        
        return arrayToHandle;
}
```

and gives the following Result:

```
(Array to remove Duplicates from)[ [CJ] ,  [DJ] ,  [DJ] ,  [C9] , [HQ] ,  [D2] ,  [HQ] ]
```

```
(Supposedly removed Duplicates)  [ [C9] ,  [D2] ,  [CJ] ,  [DJ] ,  [HQ] ,  [D2] ,  [HQ] ]
```

Comment: You *did* put all the cards from the set back into the array correctly, but the indices you *didn't* use still hold the old values. You'll need to set them to `null` *or* allocate a new array (with the new, smaller size) instead of re-using the input array. Generally speaking, you should avoid using arrays for this and just directly use collections (sets, lists, ...) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your issue is due to you are not changing the size of **arrayToHandle**, when repeated elements are removed by **Set cardSet** take into account that the size of the new array is also changing, in this case from 7 to 6,  [DJ] is removed, and when you're filling **arrayToHandle** with the new elements at the end you are not deleting the last position which is the problem you have to, try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < end; i++){
          cardSet.add(arrayToHandle[i]);
        }
arrayToHandle=new Card[cardSet.size()];///changing the size

////add the rest of your code
 
Iterator<Card> it = cardSet.iterator();
```

Comment: I see, it works now! My thought process was that it would just be empty and the size adjusted automatically. Could you explain why it put the other Cards in the place instead of a null? I thought it doesnt allow duplicates in general, therefore I dont have to adjust size.

Comment: well you can't use null here: arrayToHandle=null, if you do so you will have a null pointer exception here: arrayToHandle[counter] = it.next() , if you use null you need to use it in the position of the last element , I think it is easier if you change the whole size at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to the @Manuel Martínez answer,
but uses more recent Java code.
Caveat: I'm not an experienced lambda guy.

```
// Add stuff to the set using a lambda.
Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();
Arrays.stream(arrayToHandle).forEach(element -> stringSet.add(element));

// Create a new array from the set using a lambda.
String[] newThing;
newThing = stringSet.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
```

I don't "recommend" using lambdas,
but only because I'm still a novice with them.